# Derivation of t-statistic and p value of Regression coefficient

Tags: regression, p-value, regression-coefficients

I had this question at the back of my mind for a while. Consider any data for linear regression problem. Optimization algorithm calculates the coefficients of each feature and stops when cost function output reaches global minimum. The coefficients are single values for a given run of data.

When there are no multiple values for coefficients, how is a t-distribution generated and how are the standard error, t-statistic and p-value arrived at?

Comment: Minimum? Should I set it to negative infinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming unbiasedness of $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$ and invertibility of $X'X$, we can derive the variance of the OLS estimator as:

\begin{align}
\sigma^{2}_{\hat{\beta}_{OLS}}&=[\hat{\beta}_{OLS}-E(\hat{\beta}_{OLS})][\hat{\beta}_{OLS}-E(\hat{\beta}_{OLS})]'\\
&=[\hat{\beta}_{OLS}-\beta][\hat{\beta}_{OLS}-\beta]'\\
&=E[(X'X)^{-1}X'U][(X'X)^{-1}X'U]\\
&=E[(X'X)^{-1}X'UU'X(X'X)^{-1}]\\
&=(X'X)^{-1}X'E[UU']X(X'X)^{-1}\\
&=(X'X)^{-1}X'\sigma_{u}^2I_N X(X'X)^{-1}\\
&=\sigma_{u}^2(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1}\\
&=\sigma_{u}^2(X'X)^{-1}
\end{align}

where $\beta$ is the true (population) parameter and $\sigma_{u}^2$ is the residual variance. With an estimator $\hat{\sigma}_{u}^2$, we can then obtain standard deviations $\sigma_{\hat{\beta}_{OLS}}$ from the elements of the diagonal of $\sigma_{u}^2(X'X)^{-1}$ by taking their square root.

This allows us to build t-statistics:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\hat{\beta}_{OLS}-\beta_0}{\sigma_{\hat{\beta}_{OLS}}}
\end{equation}

which are t-distributed with $N-K$ degrees of freedom. We don't need any more information to look at such a t distribution, check where on the support this point is, and calculate how much mass is beyond* that point (i.e. calculate the p-value).

*"beyond" meaning even farther away from the mean.

Comment: I wonder if it's okay to write the matrix under the radical sign. Would it be better to put one of the diagonal elements instead?

Comment: You are right, it is lazy notation. I replaced it with text.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. could you please help with an intuitive explanation?

Comment: The main message is that you don't need "multiple values for coefficients". The t-distributions we are interested in can be fully described with a single parameter: the degrees of freedom of the t-distribution. Once we know what distribution we are talking about (i.e. once we know the degrees of freedom), we can make inference with our t-distributed statistic.